# logging times of method execution

Tags: android, performance

hi all i'm trying to find out how long a method takes to execute. the looging returns a negative float, any ideas why? thanks.

```
 method(){

startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

.....code to execute

endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
 long sampleDur = endTime - startTime;
```

.

ok i've removed the float:). i'm still getting a negative for the sample method? I'll post the actual code. It basically loops through a bitmap, sample and getRadial are methods called within that loop.

06-15 21:04:26.945: ERROR/Filters(6424): sample method took -9ms
06-15 21:04:26.945: ERROR/Filters(6424): getRadialX took 0ms
06-15 21:04:26.945: ERROR/Filters(6424): loop took 40144ms

```
    long getRadXStart = 0;
    long getRadXEnd = 0;
    long startSample = 0;
    long endSample = 0;

 long startLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
          for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                 origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);
                 getRadXStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                float x = getRadialX((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);
                getRadXEnd= System.currentTimeMillis();

                float y = getRadialY((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);

                sampleImage(input,x,y);

                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) ) <= 150 ){
                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);
                }else{
                    dst.setPixel(i,j,origPixel);
                }
              }
            }
          long endLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
          long loopDuration = endLoop - startLoop;
          long radXDuration = getRadXEnd - getRadXStart;
          long sampleDur = endSample - startSample;

          Log.e(TAG, "sample method took "+sampleDur+"ms");
          Log.e(TAG, "getRadialX took "+radXDuration+"ms");
          Log.e(TAG, "loop took "+loopDuration+"ms");

        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********filter.barrel()  looped through bm about to return dst bm");
        return dst;
    }

    void sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1)
    {
         startSample = System.currentTimeMillis();
        s = new int [4];
      if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(arr.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(arr.getWidth()-1)){
        s[0]=0;
        s[1]=0;
        s[2]=0;
        s[3]=0;
        return;
      }

      float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
      float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
      float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
      float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);

      int [] s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
      int [] s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

      float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
      float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

      s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
      s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
      s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
      s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));

      endSample = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

          Log.e(TAG, "sample method took "+(float)sampleDur+"seconds");
```

Comment: why do you convert to float? its a long.

Answer (score 1):

If removing the cast doesn't work, try this:

Log.e(TAG, "sample method took "+Long.toString(sampleDur)+" seconds");

Answer (score 0):

It's negative because `floats` are structured differently than `long`s.  There's absolutely no reason to do that.  Remove the cast to a `float` and see if it works then.